# How to show server run time in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to show date to user from how much days website is running

e.g today : runing from 10 days .  next day : running from 11 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$current = time();
$initial_date = strtotime("2017-11-1"); //You will have to fix this
$datediff = $current - $initial_date;
$num_of_days = floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
echo "Running from ".$num_of_days." days";
```

Note: This will not count today.

Answer (score 0):

This way helpful to you. first define the web site starting date as a constant as follow:

```
define('START_DATE', '2017-11-02');
```

Then you have to put below code in to the place you have to show the date difference:

```
$date1 = new DateTime(START_DATE); 
$date2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
print_r($diff); // or $diff->days

echo $diff->days . " day(s)"; // output '6 day(s)'
```

Output looks like:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 6
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 6
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)

6 day(s)
```